# How can I pull in the birthday field in a visual force email template?

Tags: visualforce

I have a birthday field (birthday_)c) which I'm trying to pull into a visual force email template, but when I try to save it i'm getting this error message:

Invalid field birthday_c for SObject Lead

But there is definitely a birthday field on a lead record with the salesforce name of "birthday_c".

Does anyone know why this isn't pulling into the visual force email?

Answer (score 2):

If the field is a standard field then it should be `Birthdate` if it is a custom field then you forgot the **double** underscore `birthday__c`

Also, you can use the field picker in the email template builder to ensure you get the correct merge fields instead of manually typing them out.

Comment: the salesforce API name is "Birthday_c" which I inputted. But I also just tried "birthday" as you suggested but I just got the same error message

Comment: Please reread my answer. DOUBLE underscore __c

Comment: @chiccaboom - No worries. Please mark as accepted answer if it solved your problem otherwise the question will keep surfacing as unanswered also so people looking for similar problem can find an answer

Comment: ya it won't let me do that atm, need to wait a few minutes, but will do so:)